# Could I use subquery value in same parent query?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT t.title, ( 
    SELECT AVG(star_rating) 
    FROM reviews r 
    WHERE r.id = t.id ) AS rating  
FROM table_1 t  
WHERE rating >= '4'
```

> PHPMYADMIN shows the error -> Unknown column 'rating' in 'where
>   clause'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this;

```
SELECT t.title, 
       (SELECT AVG(star_rating) 
        FROM reviews r 
        WHERE r.id = t.id ) AS rating 
FROM table_1 t 
WHERE (SELECT AVG(star_rating) 
       FROM reviews r 
       WHERE r.id = t.id ) >= 4
```